# jquery custom validator which calls php function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a custom validator written using the jquery plugin which calls a php page on the server to validate input using the database. I didn't know how to do this but this is the best I could come up with as I'm not a javscript/ajax programmer

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkVehicleRegistration', function(val, element) {

        var x = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "ajax/validation/checkVehicleRegistration.php",
        data: "vehicle_reg=" + val,
        success: function(resp) {

        },
        error: function(e) {alert('checkVehicleRegistration failed' + e);}
    }); 

    if (x.responseText == '0') {return true;} else {return false;}

}, 'Registration already exists');
```

Granted this is not the nicest code in the world as I've had to make the ajax call synchronous which sort of defeats the object of it all. However as I'm not a javascript programmer so its a miracle it works at all.

My problem is that the validation is really slow. jquery appears to call this validation function multiple times. I've tried using alerts to find out when the validation function is called and it seems that the validation is called multiple when you are typing in the corresponding textbox, when you tab out of the textbox and also when you submit the form.

How can I set up this custom validation function so that it is only called when the user presses submit and not when they are typing/tabbing in the textbox? Also any sugggests on a 'design pattern' for how i should have done this server side validation better using ajax are much appreciated

thanks a lot

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the plugin's built-in `remote` validation method? It uses asynchronous AJAX so it doesn't slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your own method, remote method does everything you need, for example, this is a method to validate an e-mail adress, and to check if already exists or something, plus it passes the username via post:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "check-email.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    username: function() {
                        return $( "#username" ).val();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages:{
        email:{
            remote:"Type your message here"
        }
    }
});
```

Also, you can deactivate some events so it will be more fast, for example, this will only check validation when you submit the form:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    rules: {
    }
});
```